# Algolia refinement list not selecting values properly

Tags: vue.js, algolia, vue-instant-search

I am trying to use Vue InstantSearch to search and filter users based on their attributes (hair colour, eye colour, complexion, etc).

This is how my item looks like:

```
{
 id: 1
 name: 'John',
 attribute: {
  complexion: 'Tan',
  hair_colour: 'Black',
  eye_colour: 'Brown',
  ...
}
```

This is how I am using the ais-refinement-list widget:

```
<ais-refinement-list attribute="attribute.hair_colour">...</ais-refinement-list>
<ais-refinement-list attribute="attribute.eye_colour">...</ais-refinement-list>
```

My problem is that every time I select a value from the eye colour (Brown) list, the same value in the hair colour list (Brown) is selected instead.

This how the scenario looks like:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Set attribute to searchable like the image below:

[image]